# Email Reminder Flag for Microsoft Outlook 2016

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I flag a reminder to follow up on an email. Does my email recipient also received the reminder flag or just myself?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how do you set this flag. You can set it for yourself only or for recipients:

[image]

Comment: The "Flag for Recipients" option is not displayed on my Microsoft Outlook 2016 Custom Reminder box. Do I need a different version of Outlook?

Comment: What type of Outlook account do you use (Office365/Exchange/POP3/IMAP)?

Comment: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\OUTLOOK.EXE".

Comment: It's your outlook.exe file location. And I need to know your Outlook account type (mail server type).

Comment: OUTLOOK.EXE.MANIFEST

Comment: C2RManifest.Outlook.Outlook.x-none.msi.16.x-none.xml

Comment: I'm not a Technical person, but I was able to get the info you requested.  I'm hoping what I provided will help.

Comment: There is a drop down on my "Flag to".  I changed it from "Flag for follow up" to "Reply to All".  I'm hoping all recipients will receive the follow up email.

Comment: I found my answer.  The "Flag for Recipients" window will appear before you send your email.  Once you send your email, this option will not appear.

Comment: @M.Ayala, exactly!